# Way to test (dry-run) redis-server config

Tags: redis

With nginx you can start the server, change the config file, and then run:

```
nginx -t
```

Which will tell you if the config file is valid or not before you try to restart nginx.  Is there similar functionality for redis-server?

**Edit (after deagh's answer)**

I tried `redis-server --help` but this didn't suggest it was possible... but there may still be a way that's just not documented.

Answer (score 1):

Give `redis-server --help` a chance and you will see

`Usage: ./redis-server [/path/to/redis.conf]
       ./redis-server - (read config from stdin)
       ./redis-server --test-memory <megabytes>`

There is now such option (unfortunately).

Comment: that means it's not possible via that executable - not that it's necessarily impossible to test a config file.

Comment: @AD7six thanks, that's where I was hinting.  Sorry deagh I should have put that in my question as something I had tried.  Will update it now.